# Home dashboard garbled in Joomla 4

Tags: administrator, dashboard

After transferring my site from one server to another (using Akeeba Backup), I find that the elements of the Home dashboard are wrongly arranged (see screenshot). I also get this error:

```
An error has occurred.

0 count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given
```

Everything else (back end and front end) seems to be working properly, and if I select one of the other menu options from the garbled Home dashboard the screen looks normal.

I am running Joomla 4 (updated to Joomla 4.3.3 after the transfer) using PHP 8.0.

Any help in solving this problem would be much appreciated!

Joomla version: 4.3.3
Web server: OpenLiteSpeed; same problem occurs on local Apache server under WAMP
PHP version: 8.0.29
MySQL version: 8.0.28

Thank you!

Here is the error trace:

```
1   ()  JROOT/administrator/modules/mod_loggedinusers/mod_loggedinusers.php:21
2   include()   JROOT/libraries/src/Dispatcher/ModuleDispatcher.php:52
3   Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\ModuleDispatcher::Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\{closure}()   JROOT/libraries/src/Dispatcher/ModuleDispatcher.php:55
4   Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\ModuleDispatcher->dispatch()  JROOT/libraries/src/Helper/ModuleHelper.php:281
5   Joomla\CMS\Helper\ModuleHelper::renderRawModule()   JROOT/libraries/src/Helper/ModuleHelper.php:161
6   Joomla\CMS\Helper\ModuleHelper::renderModule()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_cpanel/tmpl/cpanel/default.php:61
7   include()   JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/View/HtmlView.php:410
8   Joomla\CMS\MVC\View\HtmlView->loadTemplate()    JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/View/HtmlView.php:203
9   Joomla\CMS\MVC\View\HtmlView->display()     JROOT/administrator/components/com_cpanel/src/View/Cpanel/HtmlView.php:158
10  Joomla\Component\Cpanel\Administrator\View\Cpanel\HtmlView->display()   JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/Controller/BaseController.php:645
11  Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController->display()     JROOT/administrator/components/com_cpanel/src/Controller/DisplayController.php:56
12  Joomla\Component\Cpanel\Administrator\Controller\DisplayController->display()   JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/Controller/BaseController.php:678
13  Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController->execute()     JROOT/libraries/src/Dispatcher/ComponentDispatcher.php:143
14  Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\ComponentDispatcher->dispatch()   JROOT/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php:361
15  Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent()     JROOT/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php:143
16  Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch()     JROOT/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php:186
17  Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute()    JROOT/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php:293
18  Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()    JROOT/administrator/includes/app.php:61
19  require_once()  JROOT/administrator/index.php:32
```

Comment: Enable debug and post stack trace.

Comment: Thank you, Sharky. I have added the error trace to the OP.

Comment: The issue is in `mod_loggedinusers` module.

Comment: Any idea what I should do about that? I haven't made any changes to that module, so I'm wondering why it should give an error. It is the standard code.

Comment: This is not a core module. Check for updates or ask its developers. If the module is no longer maintained, you can try fixing the code manually. If you need help with that, post contents of `mod_loggedinusers.php`.

Comment: Ok,thank you. That solves the problem. I have just disabled the module and everything works fine. I can use the core module for logged-in users.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was caused by the mod_loggedinuser module. This is not a core module, and there is a core module which also shows logged in users. I was able to solve the problem my just disabling the non-core module.

Comment: As the module is probably written for Joomla 3 you should consider removing the 3rd party module all together.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I will do that.